# Area of trapezoid, did I count right?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area, quadrilateral

Top and bottom lines are parallel.

Trapezoid:

[image: trapezoid]]

I got ~$6397 m^2$

Comment: as Michael noted there is simething wrong, indeed  the left side should be $\geq 76 \sin 72°\approx72.28$

Comment: @Mrnotsogood  Please don't vandalize the question. Rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use:

$$A=\frac12(76\sin 72°)(100+77)=6397$$

Note that the result seems to be numerically exact [76*sin(72°)*177/2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=76*sin(72%C2%B0)*177%2F2).

However note also that the left side should be $\geq 76 \sin 72°\approx72.28$ (maybe it's a typo?).

In case the bottom and top lines were not parallel you could consider a diagonal and solve for triangles or use [Bretschneider's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula).

Notably, with reference to the following figure:

[image]

we obtain from the [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)

$$AB^2=AC^2+BC^2-2AC\cdot BC \cos 72°\implies AB=115.9$$

and thus

$$S_{ABC}=\frac12AC\cdot BC \sin 72° = 3614$$

and from [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)

$$S_{DBC}=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)} \approx 2710.65$$

and finally

$$S_{ABCD}\approx 6324.65$$

Answer (score 2):

It's $$\frac{(100+77)76\sin72^{\circ}}{2}$$ and we get your answer.

In another hand, we obtain:
$$\cos72^{\circ}=\frac{23^2+76^2-72^2}{2\cdot23\cdot76},$$ which is wrong, which says that this trapezoid does not exist.

Comment: indeed the left side should be $\geq 76 \sin 72°\approx72.28$

Comment: @gimusi Happy New Year!

Comment: Happy New Year Michael! I've calculated the exact area!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I'm missing, but isn't the area just this?

$$A = \frac{(B_1 + B_2)h}{2} = \frac{(100m+77m)72m}{2} = 6372m^2$$

($B_1,B_2$ are the two bases of the trapezoid.)

It looks like the lengths of the non-parallel sides were rounded to the nearer integer, so you have to pick one non-parallel side to be the "right" one. I also assumed that the $72$-m side was perpendicular to the bases (it appears to be so).

Comment: it's almost perpendicular but not exactly indeed as commented here below $76\cdot \sin (72°)\approx 72.28$

Comment: @gimusi Saying that the $76$ m length is exact is an assumption. Why not the $72$-m length? It's consistent down to integer rounding as well: $72m/\sin(72^{\circ}) \approx 75.71 m$. If we take all of the labeled values as exact, the trapezoid doesn't exist. So, we have to peg some of them as exact, and calculate the others.

Comment: by the infomation we have from the figure it should be a quadrilateral